# How can I import bib File to Latex?

Tags: latex, bibtex

I'm new to using Latex. I want to import File **reference.bib** to my File **document.tex**. Above is my Code

***reference.bib***

```
@article{lin1973,
   author = "Shen Lin and Brian W. Kernighan",
   title = "An Effective Heuristic Algorithm for the Travelling-Salesman Problem",
   journal = "Operations Research",
   volume = 21,
   year = 1973,
   pages = "498-516"
}
```

And here is my document.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, fleqn]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{reference}
\end{document}
```

But nothing happens when i run my Latex. Can anyone help me. 
Thanks in Advance ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a separate platform to ask [LateX-related questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).
Apart from that, the question is really vague.

Let's start with your document having no content. Assuming that your LateX environment has been set up properly, adding something to your document should do something.

Compile, run BibteX twice, compile again a few times and you should be set.
EDIT: removed screenshot output file, as it was needlessly taking up space.

BibTeX build is usually found in your interpreter:

[image: Something like this]
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt, fleqn]{scrreprt}

```
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
Blablabla happened because I need to cite \cite{lin1973}..
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{reference}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried this way, but i received : "Blablabla happened because there was a need to cite ?"

Comment: Warning : Citation 'lin1973' undefined

Comment: More compiling my friend, more compiling. Either you haven't run bibtex yet on your bibtex file, or you haven't compiled the main code enough times

Comment: i did 10 times but still get "? " :((. Must i run direct my bib File ? Or i can only use TexMarker ?

Comment: In your Latex interpreter, for me I use TeXnicCenter, there should be an option to build BibteX, I'll add another pic

Comment: In TeXworks, I think you: Compile with pdfLaTeX to get know which pieces you cite and store it in .aux file.
Compile with BibTeX to create the .bbl file (which contains the formatted references) from information stored in the .aux and .bib files.
Compile with pdfLaTex to incorporate the .bbl file in the typeset document (to include references list in the document).
Compile with pdfLaTex to rid of ? marks and get citations in your text. Hope it now works. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help :D. I did ^^